# Failed to build Xamarin.Android project with "Error XA5209: Unzipping failed"

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

After updating to el capitan I'm unable to build and run a xamarin.android project any more. I get the following error. All components of selected API level and extras are installed :

> /Users/me/.../Project.Android: Error XA5209: Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r16.zip
>   and extract it to the /Users/me/.local/share/Xamarin/Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/22.2.1/content directory. (XA5209) (MyProject.Android)

Please advise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The folder error path was referring to contained the required file `android_m2repository_r16.zip` but it was corrupted.

The solution is to remove bad file, redownload new one, unpack at the same folder. After that it began to work, build and run.